# MarkLogic ingest JSON from external API

Tags: rest, curl, marklogic-9

I am using Marklogic 9 and try to ingest data from external source into MarkLogic. I made an REST API on port 8031. When I try to execute the following curl command:

```
curl --anyauth --user admin:admin -i -X POST -d https://services7.arcgis.com/21GdwfcLrnTpiju8/arcgis/rest/services/Geluidsbelasting/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=json
-H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" \
'http://localhost:8031
```

After executing this statement I receive the error:

```
Curl: URL is not specified
```

Can you please help me out!

Many thanks

Erik

Answer (score 0):

Your `-d` parameter has special characters that are not escaped. Try putting quotes around your `-d` url. It will prevent your command from getting truncated and misinterpreted at `&` signs..

HTH!